# How can I make JLabel selectable without destroying accessibility?

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

We want to be able to select the text on some labels.

At the moment, we're using a hack where we extend `JEditorPane` and then try to style it to look identical to a `JLabel`. This seems to work fine, but really it just lulls you into a false sense of security until a user using a screen reader asks you why you're inserting an editor which is never editable. Which, funnily enough, is exactly what has happened.

As it turns out, `getAccessibleContext()` for an editor pane returns the context for an editor pane, unsurprisingly. I know I can override that method and reimplement the entirety of `JLabel.AccessibleJLabel` myself, but there are a lot of things to implement, and I feel like there must be a better way.

Is there, in fact, a better way? e.g., it seems like I should be able to do it via the Look & Feel, but maybe there is an even easier trick.

I guess ideally, I would have hoped that there were just a property on JLabel to allow making the text selectable directly, allowing us to both keep the semantics/accessibility of adding a label to the view, while also allowing us to keep the usability.

Comment: The screen reader reads it out as if it's an editor pane. :/

Comment: I'm confused, could you give an example? Does it read tags, such as <b>, when it's not supposed to? Also, [there's a related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051006/java-swing-jeditorpane-and-screen-readers), might want to check it out

Comment: It reads out something like, "You are currently on a text *field*. Type to enter text", and then the user is like, "I'm typing to enter text and nothing is happening", because apparently, a non-editable text area does not read out something to indicate that it's not editable. A real label says "You are currently on a text *element*".

Comment: (Actually, it reads out the HTML stuff too. I hadn't noticed that, but now that is bugging me.)